# Somatório coluna contas recebidas por data

Tags: postgresql

Não estou conseguindo, somar valores da coluna vrlancamento por data. A query retorna datas repetidas.

select
dtlancamento, sum(vrlancamento) as Total_Contas_Recebidas
from
caixa
inner join
pessoa on caixa.idempresa = pessoa.idpessoa
where
dtlancamento between '2021-01-04 00:00:00'
and
'2021-01-04 23:59:59'
and idcontafinanceiro in ('1')
and tpprocedencia in ('P')
and dtcancelado is null
group by
dtlancamento

Retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você está considerando o campo timestamp (data e hora). Faça o GROUP BY apenas pela parte referente a data, por exemplo: `date_trunc(dtlancamento, 'day')`.

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações, consegui executar a query por periodo.